# Cannot enumerate over float, but is there another way to go through this?

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis, enumerate

**EDIT** I am slightly embarrassed- I was using the wrong delimiter. So sorry if I wasted anyones time! The code is running now, but taking pretty long so I may be back in a couple of hours. Thanks everyone

I'm trying to use code from an online source - http://alexminnaar.com/time-series-classification-and-clustering-with-python.html - and apply it to time series data that I have in a csv file. The error that I'm running into is when it tries to enumerate through "s1". I understand that I can't enumerate over floats, but I'm not quite sure I know how to solve the problem, let alone what exactly the code needs to enumerate for. I'm certain that my dataset is formatted like his, because he has his dataset on the github report.

Thank you for any help you can give me!

**EDIT** I forgot to include the DTW function, which is now added below

function  DTWDistance

```
def DTWDistance(s1, s2,w):
    DTW={}

    w = max(w, abs(len(s1)-len(s2)))

    for i in range(-1,len(s1)):
        for j in range(-1,len(s2)):
            DTW[(i, j)] = float('inf')
    DTW[(-1, -1)] = 0

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(max(0, i-w), min(len(s2), i+w)):
            dist= (s1[i]-s2[j])**2
            DTW[(i, j)] = dist + min(DTW[(i-1, j)],DTW[(i, j-1)], DTW[(i-1, j-1)])

    return math.sqrt(DTW[len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1])
```

function LB_Keogh

```
def LB_Keogh(s1,s2,r):
    LB_sum=0
    for ind,i in enumerate(s1):

        lower_bound=min(s2[(ind-r if ind-r>=0 else 0):(ind+r)])
        upper_bound=max(s2[(ind-r if ind-r>=0 else 0):(ind+r)])

        if i>upper_bound:
            LB_sum=LB_sum+(i-upper_bound)**2
        elif i<lower_bound:
            LB_sum=LB_sum+(i-lower_bound)**2

    return math.sqrt(LB_sum)
```

function k_means_clust

```
def k_means_clust(data,num_clust,num_iter,w=5):
    centroids=random.sample(data,num_clust)
    counter=0
    for n in range(num_iter):
        counter+=1
        print (counter)
        assignments={}
        #assign data points to clusters
        for ind,i in enumerate(data):
            min_dist=float('inf')
            closest_clust=None
            for c_ind,j in enumerate(centroids):
                if LB_Keogh(i,j,5)<min_dist:
                    cur_dist=DTWDistance(i,j,w)
                    if cur_dist<min_dist:
                        min_dist=cur_dist
                        closest_clust=c_ind
            if closest_clust in assignments:
                assignments[closest_clust].append(ind)
            else:
                assignments[closest_clust]=[]

        #recalculate centroids of clusters
        for key in assignments:
            clust_sum=0
            for k in assignments[key]:
                clust_sum=clust_sum+data[k]
            centroids[key]=[m/len(assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum]

    return centroids
```

data:

```
time_series=np.genfromtxt('filepath')
```

call to function

```
centroids=k_means_clust(list(time_series),4,10,4)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-50-909588871671> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 centroids=k_means_clust(list(df),4,10,4)
      9 
     10 

<ipython-input-49-f91bbc3a5a04> in k_means_clust(data, num_clust, num_iter, w)
     11             closest_clust=None
     12             for c_ind,j in enumerate(centroids):
---> 13                 if LB_Keogh(i,j,5)<min_dist:
     14                     cur_dist=DTWDistance(i,j,w)
     15                     if cur_dist<min_dist:

<ipython-input-48-b5b8e44a435a> in LB_Keogh(s1, s2, r)
      1 def LB_Keogh(s1,s2,r):
      2     LB_sum=0
----> 3     for ind,i in enumerate(s1):
      4 
      5         lower_bound=min(s2[(ind-r if ind-r>=0 else 0):(ind+r)])

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You mentioned trying to use his data and run the code, could you [download and try the jupyter notebook](https://github.com/alexminnaar/time-series-classification-and-clustering/blob/master/Time%20Series%20Classification%20and%20Clustering.ipynb)? That would allow you to run the cells and not copy and paste code since it's all there. If you aren't familiar with jupyter I recommend this [tutorial to install on a server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04), but you could also install locally on your computer via a virt

Comment: I am using jupyter, thanks for your reply! I have figured out my problem

Comment: Rewrite your code in Cython, because pure python is *way* too slow for such things.